# Change redundant value SPSS 23

Tags: parameters, spss

While working in SPSS I did a GLM Univariate analysis to obtain a Parameter Estimates table. This analysis sets the last value of a series to zero. Now I want to set another value to zero (as redundant value), in my case COW_nr=0. How do I do this?[My parameter estimates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqJt7.jpg)

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use the constrast specification (the /contrasts subcommand or subdialog box) to set a reference categories for an appropriate contrast.